# Get all text from WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, winforms, browser

I have a WebBrowser control and I will like to get all the text from that control. In other words I will like to get the same text that if I where to grab my mouse select everything from the browser and paste it in notepad. I know there are several techniques to get the text such as WebBrowser.DocumentText or innerhtml but none of those techniques gives the same text that I would get if I where to copy everything from the browser to the clipboard.

Comment: I think there is diffrent charset in WebBrowser.DocumentText and you can say it to WebBrowser.DocumentText to get your needed charset

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
webBrowser1.Document.ExecCommand("SelectAll", false, null);
webBrowser1.Document.ExecCommand("Copy", false, null);
```