# I want to select all and copy it to clipboard

Tags: c#

I have a WebBrowser displaying text.
If i copy it to clipbaord it copy's all the html tags to and i don't want that.

I want to be able to **select all** then copy to clipboard.

I want to copy the **text and its formatting** to the clipboard.

When i highlight the text my self and click copy when i paste, its perfect just how i want it.

But when i use this code to copy just the Document text i get the Html tags to.

This is how i copy to clipboard:

```
void CopyCellText()
{
Clipboard.Clear();
if (webBrowser1 != null)
{
Clipboard.SetText(webBrowser1.DocumentText.ToString().Trim());
}
}
```

Comment: The formatting of HTML text is controlled by it's tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Select all and copy to clipboard:

```
webBrowser1.Document.ExecCommand("SelectAll", true, null);
webBrowser1.Document.ExecCommand("Copy", true, null);
```

You wont see the html tags but have all there formatting.

Comment: This is more like a hack and can be discontinued, if you wanted to retain all format there are tools like [XHTML to RTF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7087/XHTML2RTF-An-HTML-to-RTF-conversion-tool-based-on)

Answer (score 1):

You mean you want to convert your html code to text and copy to clipboard? You will need [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). Check [this page](http://olussier.net/2010/03/30/easily-parse-html-documents-in-csharp/) for an easy guide.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet1921.htm << check this code snippet. it would be better, if you strip the string while using regex!

Comment: Regex and Html [do not match very well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), plus the OP wants to keep formatting!

Comment: did't know that, because i've never used smth like this! thanks!

Comment: This is good, but i would like to keep the html formatting, my highlighting and underlines and cross outs, How do i select all?

Comment: it's not as easy as i thought, but i found this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2007/01/21/html-clipboard.aspx?Redirected=true

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason you are getting the HTML tags is `webBrowser1.DocumentText` will take the entire content of the HTML document itself, which will include all the generated HTML.

A quick search gave me the following:

[Retrieving Selected Text from Webbrowser control in .net(C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217353/retrieving-selected-text-from-webbrowser-control-in-netc)

[Get all text from WebBrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570125/get-all-text-from-webbrowser-control)